# How can I type fractions with a customized bar?

Tags: fractions

I would like to typeset fractions with the following customized bar (with little edges see below); this is related to continued fractions. Of course the example below is very simple but it should be resizeable since I need to use it with rather complicated expressions. How could I achieve it? Regards.

[image]

Comment: Could you give us a MWE ?

Comment: @flav Are you speaking of a more reliable scan? Here is one form Marc Guinot's book concerning Lagrange and Legendre, p. 61). Regards.

Comment: Not a new scan, but [some basic code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/) to demonstrate how far you have got in tackling your problem; see also "[What makes a good MWE?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3343/)"

Comment: @Dɑvïd Oh, I see. But this seems to be a very tricky typesetting. I don't see how I could do. I browsed the web with some related keywords in case I could find some similar example but with no success. Regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\zfrac[2]{{\tabcolsep=2pt\begin{array}{c}%
#1\\
\noalign{\vskip-7pt}
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{\rule[-3pt]{.4pt}{3pt}\hrulefill\rule{.4pt}{3pt}}\\
\noalign{\vskip-2pt}
#2\end{array}}}

\begin{document}


\[
\frac{1}{2} + \zfrac{1}{2} + \zfrac{111}{222}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd rather use `\rule[-2.6pt]{.4pt}{3pt}`.

Comment: @Werner yes possibly, and wrap it all in mathchoice so it works in scripts but....

Comment: @ThomasBaruchel Werner's adjustment would give slightly better corners between the rules.